# prettier ESLint circular errors

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier

i am creating a vue component

but i am getting the following error

```
Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.
```

if i remove the type clause i then get

```
Missing return type on function.
```

the component looks like:

```
<template>
    <pre>Market:{{ market }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import Market from "./Market";

export default {
    name: Market,
    components: {},
    data() { //<--- issue is reported here
        return {
            market: new Market(),
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

i'm guessing i have a conflict in prettier and eslints config so that one is treating vue as TS compatableand the other isn't

i've tried various tweaks and changes but nothing so far has made any diference so can any one point me to the correct config to resolve this?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
};
```

settings,json

```
{
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "php-cs-fixer.executablePath": "${extensionPath}\\php-cs-fixer.phar",
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
    },
    "debug.javascript.usePreview": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 3,
    "eslint.format.enable": true
}
```

packange.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended",
      "@vue/prettier",
      "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: *prettier and eslints config* - which config? The question has none. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The problem you describe doesn't make sense in general as TS linter rules aren't supposed to be used for JS code. It's unknown where the error occurs. If it happens in IDE and not linter command then the problem is misidentified.

Comment: if i knew which element of the config was the issue i would know which element to override, and as i said i have tried numerous things to try and correct this so i've orhaned attempts to fix scattered everywhere so if you would like to tell me which config(s) you want to see i'd be happy to add it to the question

Comment: Obviously, eslint/prettier configs, but any others that affects the problem. You should be able to reproduce it from scratch in order for others will be able to do the same, so it becomes evident which configs affect it. A repo my be helpful. Again, it's unknown how you get this error. The question should clearly state which are the steps to reproduce it. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The question needs to conform the rules to be constructive.

Comment: no specific eslint/prettier configs as i'm assuming that i will need to create some to override the problematic default

Comment: The question doesn't specifically mention that you intentionally use TypeScript. If you don't, `@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint`, etc shouldn't be there. If you do then it's like the answer says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already had the same issue, fix it with:

```
<script lang="ts">
    ...
</script>
```

let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks, so i was looking in completely the wrong location

Comment: This doesn’t actually fix the issue, just workaround it. OP is not trying to use TS.